# Interview Question, what's limiting the output frequency for the FPGA circuit?

Tags: fpga, frequency, interview-questions

I recently received a question in an interview that partially stumped me.  It went something like this:

You have an FPGA circuit that is supposed to be generating a signal with a frequency of 500MHz, but is only outputting at 300MHz.  **How would you go about troubleshooting this and finding out the cause of delay?**

My first reaction was to check the impedance and capacitance across the circuit to see if it was somehow acting as a lowpass filter, but aside from that I couldn't think of any ideas.  Can someone help me out, is there an obvious answer that I'm missing?

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but capacitance is a form of impedance, or, more specifically, reactance.  Two of capacitance, inductance, and resistance must be present in various configurations to form a low-pass filter.  But, as allanw pointed out, this won't change the frequency of the signal.

Comment: Ah, duh, I'm sorry it's been a while since my old EE classes.  I was thinking impedance was a synonym for resistance.

Comment: @John, in the future don't immediately accept the first answer you get, particularly for questions like yours where there is no definitive answer you can go and check that it "works". You're basically discouraging people from giving you more complete and comprehensive answers -- there's no reason to rush with accepting answers.

Comment: @saar, I may have been a bit hasty because I am more used to the stackoverflow community, where if a question is answered after a day, it's rarely returned to be answered by other developers, even if it is not accepted.  I actually think the community on electronics.stackexchange is much more constructive, perhaps because there's not as many posts.  It's an issue I think should be brought up on meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are most likely referring to the design failing the timing constraints (I.E., the FPGA compiler reports that things are going slower).  So, the solution would be to look at the timing report file and try to narrow things down from there.

It's hard to say anything beyond this first step because it is very design dependant-- and that info wasn't given in the interview question.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.  If the employer were to give me a design, however, what would I be looking for in regards to controlling the frequency?  Or would I still be reliant on the timing report?  I guess I'm asking what kind of design flaws there could be that would affect the frequency of a system.

Comment: @John  The #1 thing that would limit the max freq is the signal routing and combinatorial logic between two flip-flops.  The design flaw is that there is too much routing and logic between FF's.  But that doesn't really address your question because 99% of an FPGA logic is signal routing, combinatorial logic, and flip-flops.  You really can't narrow it down more than that without actually seeing the design.

Comment: The term that Altera uses is "slack time". It's defined as the amount of time between a flip-flop's input settling and the start of its setup time. If this is negative, you need to redesign, e.g. by pipelining the logic.

Answer (score 4):

The question they asked you is pretty badly phrased (unless you omitted some details, or they wanted to check that you're listening).

If the FPGA is clocked at 500 MHz, but the design can only handle 300 MHz, then the "signal" doesn't matter, as the entire design won't work correctly. To fix that, check the timing report to see where the critical paths are. Those paths are the "slowest" ones between two elements, and determine the maximum clock frequency the circuit in the clock domain can achieve in a synchronous design. Then you go to the HDL to look at the offending blocks and see how you can make those paths shorter by introducing pipelining, for example. A more advanced option is to look at the placed-and-routed design in a GUI editor and see if the placer did something silly which led to the long paths. You can then hand-place the blocks or try different placement seeds.

If the FPGA design can handle 500 MHz, but only one signal is outputting 300 MHz instead of 500 MHz, then you were on the right track. You'd need to make sure that the I/O standard you're using is rated for 500 MHz; check if the I/O's drive strength is set correctly; check the impedance of the traces and for mismatches; debug the traces with a scope and spectrum analyzer; and simulate the circuit with HyperLynx, for example.

Finally, it could be that your measuring equipment isn't appropriate and you're affecting the signal you're attempting to look at. So you could have asked them what the measurement setup was.

Answer (score 3):

A low pass filter wouldn't change the frequency of the signal, only slow the transition edges down.

Comment: Although this is correct and needed to be explained to the op, this is not a complete answer to the question.